# How to get viewed picture id using jquery waypoint?

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I have installed the waypoint plugin, and everything works great. I can fire up an alert when I scroll down the pictures. I get an alert for each picture when I get to it. But what I want to do is get the html value of the picture that I am on.

Let me explain by code:

```
$('.Picture-1A').waypoint(function(direction){
    if(direction == 'down'){
        $(this).html(); // this won't work. Undefined.
    }
});
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="Picture-1A">
    <span style="display:none" class="PictureID">45</span>
    <span style="display:none" class="UserID">1</span>
</div>
<div class="Picture-1A">
    <span style="display:none" class="PictureID">48</span>
    <span style="display:none" class="UserID">1</span>
</div>
```

What I want to do is get `PictureID` of the current picture that I am doing and do database manipulation on it using Ajax and PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$(this.element)` instead of `$(this)`. Since `this` seems to refer to a Waypoint object.

To get the value inside the `span` tag with class `PictureID`, try `$(this.element).children(".PictureID").first().text()`. In your code, this should return `45` if triggered on the first `.Picture-1A`.

Comment: What are the element properties? $(this.element.id) returns null. How can I get PictureID using this.element? because it still returns ObjectHTMLDivElement

Comment: how about `var id = $(this.element).children(".PictureID").first().text()`

Comment: @FarrisFahad No problem. I would very much appreciate it if you can mark this answer as the accepted answer. Thanks.